# .map para recorrer un array de objetos React

Tags: reactjs

Estoy importando un array de objetos hotelsData, lo paso en los props al componente Hotel card quiero recorrer el array con .map para mostrar la propiedad name de cada uno de los objetos, si lo hago por consola se muestra bien, pero no he podido mostrarlo en la vista por que me muestra el siguiente error

> Error: HotelCard(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually
> means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return
> null

tambein trate de hacer esto

```
c = Array.from(props.hotelsData)
```

y recorro c pero muestra el mismo error:

Como podría corregir esto

Gracias por la ayuda.

```
import hotelsData from './data.js';   
    
     function App() {
          return (
            <div className="App">
                <HotelCard hotelsData={hotelsData}/>
            </div>
          );
        }
        
        
        const HotelCard = (props) => {
          {
            props.hotelsData.map(item => {
              console.log(item.name);
              return (
                <div>
                  <div key={item.name}>{item.name}</div>
                </div>
              )
            })
          }
        }



export default App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como te menciona el error, te falta el `return` en el componente para poder renderizarlo en el DOM, lo mismo que le haces al componente `App`

```
const HotelCard = props => {
   return (
      props.hotelsData.map(/.../)
   )
}
```

Con esto deberia bastar :D

Comment: Pensé que solo se podía un return por componente y que se aplicaba solo para devolver jsx. Gracias